# sleep X - won't actually make bash script loop wait

Tags: bash, xdotool

I need to run this really simple script to serve my purpose:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]; do
    xdotool mousemove 2980 690 click 1 &
    sleep 14
done
```

it's to make Xsane (scanner lamp) scan every few seconds... well it does, but does not wait any second, it just continues immediately.

This is just temporary solution, I will make it work with non active window and buttons relative location (to window) etc. etc. But what bugs me now is that it won't sleep. Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This 'mistiming' might be because your make your `xdotool` run in the **background** - you do it with `&` at the end of your command.

Comment: I tried what you suggested (removing &), but the result is the same :/

Comment: You sure it doesn't wait? For debug purposes add `date` line just before `sleep  14`, it should report system time every ~14 seconds.

Comment: It does... it takes exactly 14 seconds. I guess counting in my head wasn't accurate enough. Thank you for reminding me how dumb I am :D.

Comment: @MiHa we all are, wich makes us able to learn ;)